# How to RPM install the web service itself from web?

Tags: rpm, zypper

Hi please allow me to make another thread to make it clear.
The original issue is here,
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35529347/zypper-failed-in-web-install-but-works-fine-from-cmdline-install

At first we upload a webServer.iso in the web GUI, then click "install" button to install it, basically calls install.py which runs zypper install.

Our web server is running as a service. In SLES12 each service has a myService.service configure file which has a stop/start service entry.

Then we found the REAL issue is like this, zypper calls RPM, RPM calls stop service entry which killed the web process and its install.py subprocess.
We killed ourselves in the middle of the install.

I'm new to RPM, so what's the proper way to handle this case please ? Thank you !

Comment: How about running your zypper install process as a background process then? Since you are trying to update yourself (if I understand it well); this might be a solution.

Comment: Well, the problem is, it's the web server spawns the zypper install, so even in background, it's still the child of the web server process. So when web server is stopped, its child is killed as well i guess. I end up adding a separate service doing the install, and web server sends a signal to it to start the install.

Comment: That is a cleaner solution.